# Unable to get only one div to appear at a time in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list `<ul id="project_menu">` of items stacked vertically on the left, and every time an item is clicked from that list, a div (`project-details`) slowly fades in on the right side of the screen to display more info. Now, I only want one div to appear at a time, so if the user clicks item A, then item B, then item D, I want all other divs to disappear except the one last clicked(D). To that end, I wrote my own code in jQuery but it does not work.

Here are the relevant files:

```
<div class="project">
    <ul id="project_menu" class="project_menu">
        <li id="menu-php-mysql" data-projectID="php-project">PHP/MySQL</li>
        <li id="menu-nodejs" data-projectID="node-project">NodeJS</li> 
        <!-- more code -->
    </ul>
    <div class="project-detail">
        <div id="php-project">
            <i class="ion-ios-close-empty close-icon js-close-icon"></i>
            <div classs="project-text">
                <!-- data about project -->
            </div>
            <div id="node-project">
                <i class="ion-ios-close-empty close-icon js-close-icon"></i>
                <div classs="project-text">
                    <!-- data about project -->
                </div> 
                <!-- and so on.. -->
```

```css
#php-project {
    background-color: #9b59b6;
    margin: 30px;
    display: none;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    itemsToRender = [];
    $('ul#project_menu li').click(function(e) {
        menuItemId = (e.currentTarget.id);
        itemsToRender.push(menuItemId);
        var listSize = itemsToRender.length;              

        if (listSize > 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < listSize - 1; i++) {
                currentItemId = itemsToRender[i];                
                $(getProjectId(currentItemId)).css('display', 'none');              
            }
            menuItemId = itemsToRender.pop();
            $(getProjectId(menuItemId)).fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
            $(getProjectId(menuItemId)).fadeIn('slow');
        }

        console.log(itemsToRender);
    });

    $('i.js-close-icon').click(function(e) { 
        projectId = (e.currentTarget.parentElement.id);
        console.log(projectId);    
        $('#' + projectId).fadeOut('slow');
    });
});

function getProjectId(menuItemId) {
    if (menuItemId.indexOf('php') > 0) { 
        return '#php-project';
    } else if (menuItemId.indexOf('node') > 0) {
        return '#node-project';
    } else if (menuItemId.indexOf('angular') > 0) {
        return '#angular-project';
    } else if (menuItemId.indexOf('mean') > 0) {
        return '#mean-project';
    }
}
```

What I tried to do was create an array which has all the item Ids that user clicked, and set all the corresponding divs's display to hidden except the last element of the array, which is the one displayed.

Now, if I load the page and click php, the corresponding div appears on the right.If I then click nodeJS, php div disappears and node div appears. If I click on the php div again, the php div appears, and it stacks on top of the node div (which doesn't disappear!). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After all `itemsToRender` `pop` array will ne blank. and you are getting nothing in `$(getProjectId(menuItemId)).fadeIn('slow');` and do not need to use any array it quite simple as answer given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy, Just assign a class `.common` to all the items, then when you want to show one item, lets say `#id3`, you can do as follows.

```
// on event xyz....
jQuery(".common").hide();
jQuery("#id3").show();
```

Furthermore you can enhance by using the callback function as below.

```
// on event xyz....
jQuery(".common").hide(function(){
 jQuery("#id3").show();
});
```

Comment: Wow, you just made me feel like a fool for writing all that code when all it took was 3 lines. Good job!

Comment: I can totally relate, In my initial days, I too used to do all the trickery and bend head over heels to do simple tasks, but then ... I took an arrow to the knee ;) just kidding, glad that my answer helped.

Comment: Nice Skyrim reference, would upvote again if I could. Thank you (:

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul#project_menu li').click(function(e) {
   $project_id = $(this).attr("data-projectID"); //Get the project id wish to display
   $(".all_projects").hide(); //Hide all projects
   $("#"+$project_id).show(); //Show lastly clicked project
}
```

give common class for all project divs. Here i given as all_projects